# PowerQuery ODBC Connection - DataSource.Error: decimal value out of range - SQL Query

Tags: sql, odbc, powerquery

I created a ODBC connection through PowerQuery. The value column is causing the following error:

DataSource.Error: The ODBC driver returned a decimal value for column X, that we couldn't understand or is out of range.

It seems that the errors are caused mostly by values of around 0 with more than 6 decimal when the data is loaded directly to PowerQuery. If I load the connection directly to an excel table, there are no errors.

The SQL code I am using is simply selecting the desired columns with couple of conditions (SELECT, FROM, WHERE). I am not adept with SQL yet.

Is there a some kind of Format or Rounding I can apply to the selected value column directly in the query so that the data is transformed in a format that PowerQuery is able to read before being loaded to PowerQuery?

Or any other possible solutions to fix this error?

Any input is appreciated.

Thank you.